# LEFT JOIN with a table twice to get separate records

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get an aggregate count of the absent and present days of all employees by left joining the `employees` table with the `attendance_chart` table which contains the record of presence in the `attendance_status` column

```
SELECT
    e.id AS employee_id,
    COUNT(present_days_chart.id) as present_days_count,
    COUNT(absent_days_chart.id) as absent_days_count

FROM
    employees e
    LEFT JOIN attendance_chart present_days_chart ON e.id = present_days_chart.attendance_for_employee_id AND present_days_chart.attendance_status = 'present'
    LEFT JOIN attendance_chart absent_days_chart ON e.id = absent_days_chart.attendance_for_employee_id AND absent_days_chart.attendance_status = 'absent'

WHERE
    e.id IN (106,138)

GROUP BY
    e.id
```

However, the query keeps returning me the same number of records in the present_days_count and absent_days_count columns for every row.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: rbr94's answer is correct. I'll just add that if you want to know why, try to select * to see what you were actually counting (a left join will add all necessary rows, duplicating rows from the original table)

Comment: The reason is: With two LEFT JOINs on the same table you create something like a CROSS JOIN. The result is a product of present and absent days. Only for employees who have either no present or no absent days you will get a correct result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `CASE WHEN` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT e.id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN days_chart.attendance_status = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS present_days_count , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN days_chart.attendance_status = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absent_days_count

FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN attendance_chart days_chart ON e.id = days_chart.attendance_for_employee_id
WHERE e.id in (106,138)
GROUP BY e.id
```

With this `SUM` + `CASE WHEN` structure it should count every record which has the specific `attendance_status` and sums up all counts in the end with the help of `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your WHERE condition will convert the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN. Better use `e.id` like in original query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rewriting it a bit differently?

```
    SELECT
    e.id AS employee_id,
    COUNT(present_days_chart.id) as present_days_count,
    COUNT(absent_days_chart.id) as absent_days_count

FROM
    employees e
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM attendance_chart WHERE attendance_status = 'present') AS present_days_chart ON e.id = present_days_chart.attendance_for_employee_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM attendance_chart WHERE attendance_status = 'absent') AS absent_days_chart ON e.id = absent_days_chart.attendance_for_employee_id

WHERE
    e.id IN (106,138)

GROUP BY
    e.id
```

Comment: Nope. Tried it and still returns the same rows.